# Point marker disabled on normal state and enabled on select and hover states - it is not working for select state

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts 3.0.1 and there is a bug when trying to display point markers just on select state and on normal state to be disabled. 
Below can be found the link for my test:

http://jsfiddle.net/mihaelaCiocoiu/BFUF2/1/

and the corresponding code is:

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled:false,
                states: {                       
                    select: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
},function(chart){
    chart.series[0].data[1].select();
});
```

In the above code can be seen that the second point from the line is selected after the chart is rendered.

The display of the points markers on hover state is working when normal state is disabled like in the example from API Doc
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-enabled-false/, but for selected point marker is not working.

Does anybody found a solution for this problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand this bug, can you please re-write it?

Answer (score 0):

Set `radius:10` for that selected status: http://jsfiddle.net/BFUF2/8/

However, there is an issue if radius for hover and select states is different. Reported: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1867